# Calculate a running return in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a df with daily return rates. I inserted a column to start with an initial investment of $100 for day 1. I'm trying to calculate the running return each day as below

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'day': [1, 2, 3], 'return': [1.00, 1.04, 1.02], 'init_invest': [100, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Let's call the new column "value"
In this example, I'd like to see

```
Day 1 value = 100 x 1.00 = 100
Day 2 value = 100 x 1.04 = 104
Day 3 value = 104 x 1.02 = 106.08
```

At first I thought I needed to use shift here, but that hasn't worked out. How can I create this new calculation multiplying rate* the prior row's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, since you know all the returns, you can use that directly for calculation.

```
Day 1 value is given.
Day 2 value = day 1 value * 1.04 = 104
Day 3 value = day 1 value * 1.04 * 1.02 = 106.08
```

```
df["init_invest"] = df["return"].cumprod() * df["init_invest"].iloc[0]

   day  return  init_invest
0    1    1.00       100.00
1    2    1.04       104.00
2    3    1.02       106.08
``
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following here. Can you explain what you're doing? I think there's a typo setting init_invest but it's not shown that way in your output

Comment: @brooks08 I just fixed the typo in the column name. The idea is, the total return for day `n` can be calculated as: `100 * (return_day2) * (return_day3) * ... * (return_dayn)`, which means that as long as you can calculate the return percentage for that day, you can just multiply that with the initial investment value which in your case is the first value in `init_invest` column. Therefore you don't need the middle values in the `init_invest` column to be able to calculate the next day's value.